# Specify branch name during git pull to avoid pulling from default branch

Tags: git, git-pull

I have below conditions my .yml file that is run to do the deployment to windows server.

1. If folder 'ABC' does not exist in windows server, then create a folder 'ABC' and execute below command

`git clone --branch master https://git-token@github.com/username/repo.git master\`

2. If folder 'ABC' already exists, then just do a pull using below command to pull latest changes

`git pull https://git-token@github.com/username/repo.git`

Problem is, when it executes step 2, instead of pulling from 'master' branch, code is being pulled from 'Dev' branch since 'Dev' is the default branch in github (I would not want to change the default branch) and we are not specifying branch in the git pull command.

Can you please help me with the single git pull command (as in step 2) in which we specify the branch name as well. This needs to be a single pull command since .yml script is allowing to use only one command here.

I tried below options and these threw errors saying git command is invalid

`git pull --branch master https://git-token@github.com/username/repo.git master\`

`git pull origin master  https://git-token@github.com/username/repo.git`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is perfectly valid.
You have specified `origin` as well as the Remote URL.

The command that you need:

- `git pull REMOTE_URL BRANCH_NAME`

`origin` will only work if the git config has an `origin` setup. You can consider `origin` to be a variable that holds the URL to the Remote Repo. (You usually set it when you are initialising the Git repo)

**Note:**

- `git pull --ff-only` can be used if you want the merge to be fast-forwarded.

### What if there is a conflicting history?

`git pull --ff-only` won't work in that case and since,  this command is going to be a part of an automated deployment, you can't manually resolve the conflicts.
In this case use:

- `git fetch REMOTE_URL BRANCH_NAME && git reset --hard FETCH_HEAD`

This will perform a `git fetch` followed by a hard reset.

Comment: Are you sure you want to say "it will only succeed if [it] can be fast-forwared"? Because that is not true at all.

Comment: @j6t Thank you for pointing that out. I forgot to specify the `ff-only` flag. Since this is part of automated deployment, there will be no way to manually resolve conflicts.

Comment: But OP does not need `--ff-only`. Why mention it? Just remove that and the wrong warning, and your answer would be great.

Comment: Also, currently git pull command updates only the changed files in 'ABC' folder keeping timestamps of other unaffected files the same. Would the command mentioned above do the same? changing only the affected files?

Comment: @PavanKumar yes, `git pull` only pulls in the changes. It will never try to modify an existing file if no change exists.

Comment: Hi @SNikhill I tried to use the git pull command you suggested. However, as you rightly mentioned, there were conflicts and hence git pull was not successful. So in this case, are you suggesting usage of "git fetch REMOTE_URL BRANCH_NAME && git reset --hard FETCH_HEAD"? Is there any harm in using this instead of git pull command? Also, as I mentioned I want only the affected files to be updated. Will the git fetch command take care of this?

Comment: Basically, how do I do a forceful git pull?

Comment: @PavanKumar a fetch followed by a hard reset is FORCEFULL. It will basically force the local repo to have the same history (and hence, same commits) as the remote repo.